Java 17 HttpClient- socket keepalive
Apache's HttpClient provides mechanism to keep the socket alive.
 SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive(true).build();
 new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager().setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)

Is there a way to enable TCP keep alive using Java 17 HttpClient?

Why? Isn’t one keepalive mechanism enough? Are you really going to keep these HTTP connections open for two hours?

How about just adding a keep-alive header to your http request?
for example
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("host"))
.header("Connection", "keep-alive")
.POST(json.body)).build()


Not the same thing, although maybe the OP thinks it is, and anyway it's on by default from HTTP 1.1.
